# New line symbol into variable batch

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am having one annoying problem while writing script in batch.

```
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (xxtempLinkMulti3.txt) do set LinkMulti2=!LinkMulti2!%%x
```

input xxtempLinkMulti3.txt looks like

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.facebook.com
www.linkedin.com
```

Code is working fine, but when i want to echo my variable the result is:

```
www.google.comwww.yahoo.comwww.facebook.comwww.linkedin.com
```

but it should be excatly like output. (with new lines signs)(i've tried using "^" sign between !LinkMulti2! and %%x but it didn't affect on the output.

Please help.thanks. It may be other way to save from file to variable (perfectly the same, with new line signs).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem get new-line into variable (note the two empty lines which are mandatory)
set NewLine=^


for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (xxtempLinkMulti3.txt) do set LinkMulti2=!LinkMulti2!%%x!NewLine!

echo !LinkMulti2!

endlocal
```

Note that empty lines in the original file are *not* included.

You need delayed expansion in order to echo the string correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to concatenate the lines into a single line?

`for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (xxtempLinkMulti3.txt) do echo %%x` will do just fine.

And why do you need to save all of it as a variable? You can `type` it and it will display all the words in the text file.